# Is the Intern really able to run on any Selenium service?

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, intern

I've written some functional tests for [the Intern](https://theintern.github.io/), which supposedly should work on SauceLabs, BrowserStack, TestingBot, *or* my own Selenium grid.

The same code doesn't seem to work on all services though. I initially got the functional tests working on SauceLabs, so I'm using that service as my "base", so to speak.

On BrowserStack, the tests appeared to fail because the commands were executing too quickly. For example, I am using `.pressKeys('TEST\nIN\nPROGRESS\n')`, where `\n` is supposed to execute javascript on the page to turn the previous text into a tag (like the SO tags for this question: `[intern] [javascript] [testing]`).

That command should result in the following:

```
[TEST] [IN] [PROGRESS]
```

but instead results in

```
[TESTIN] [PROGRESS]
```

causing my assertions to fail. Changing the `pressKeys` command to

```
.pressKeys('TEST\n')
.sleep(500)
.pressKeys('IN\n')
.sleep(500)
.pressKeys('PROGRESS\n')
```

did not solve the issue. The test would pass / fail inconsistently, with the tags *sometimes* coming out as `[TEST] [IN] [PROGRESS]`, and sometimes as `[TESTIN] [PROGRESS]`.

Another example is that it wouldn't always wait for the next page to load when I `.click()` on a link, even with a `.sleep()` command after.

With regards to TestingBot, the application flat-out failed to upload files, and I could not for the life of me figure out how to enable the `file_watcher` service required to do so. They have a [file upload example here](https://testingbot.com/support/other/uploads), but I don't know how to configure the Intern to do this for me.

Isn't the Intern supposed to take care of these differences in the cloud providers for the tests?

Is there some standardized way of writing my tests in the Intern so that I can change my cloud testing provider without changing the tests themselves?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be possible to run the same test suite against any cloud-hosted Selenium providers and have them execute successfully, but there are some things you must do:

1. You need to make sure you’ve correctly configured providers so they all run the same version of Selenium. There is no standard for this; each provider uses a different key to decide which Selenium version to run. Check each provider’s documentation for the correct key to use.
2. You need to write tests that don’t have race conditions. What you’re describing here sounds like a classic race condition where you are performing some action that completes asynchronously, and so only happens in environments that execute operations within a certain period of time. Modifying this specific test so it has a [find timeout](http://theintern.github.io/leadfoot/Command.html#setFindTimeout) and then tries to `find` the element you expect to be generated when the return key is hit should be a good solution, since this will allow you to wait as long as necessary without making your test slow.

Unfortunately, even with this advice, all of the cloud-hosted providers for Web browser testing are garbage and mess with things in a way that randomly causes tests to break. BrowserStack is the best by far at avoiding this, but even they do things to break tests from time to time that work perfectly well in a locally hosted Selenium installation.

For file uploads, Intern will automatically upload files if has detected that the remote provider supports it, and you `type` a valid path to a file on the server where `intern-runner` is running. You can check whether the server supports uploads by looking at `this.remote.session.capabilities.remoteFiles`. Feature detection must be turned on for this to work, and you should run Intern 3.0.6 or newer if you are trying to upload files to a Selenium server on the same machine as `intern-runner`.

Comment: With regards to the race conditions, that's exactly what's happening here. The find timeout doesn't resolve the issue I was having with the return key not registering though--I need to literally slow down the commands, which `sleep()` doesn't seem to be doing.

Comment: It might help if you show the entire test instead of just this part of the test, if that advice isn’t working, since there might be a secondary problem in the code not represented in the OP.

Comment: I've created a [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MaBpXR?editors=001) containing the full failing test in question.

Comment: The pasted code is not doing what I suggested to do. It should separate the "TEST\n", "IN\n", and "PROGRESS\n" into 3 separate type commands. After each, insert a `find` call that looks for the element that was supposed to be generated once the enter key was hit. That way you don’t start typing for the second element until the first one has been correctly generated. Incidentally this may indicate your code will fail under the control of a fast typist, though without access to the code itself I couldn’t say for sure.

Comment: OH! I see what you mean by the `find` command--I had thought you wanted me to find the input I was already in, and not the HTML elements created with a tag. That makes a lot of sense. One last question--is there any way to get rid of race conditions for a URL click? Does the find timeout take care of that?